# Reverse Ajax implementation using javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reverse-ajax

Please help me out.
Doubt: Is reverse Ajax implementation requires server side implementation also? 
Prob: I read about reverse ajax and I know also how it works but don't know how to implement it?

Comment: And what do you mean by *"reverse ajax"*, just pushing from the server, like Comet or sockets, or something else ?

Comment: if you can't implement it, you don't know how it works. You also have a doubt that you need server side implementation ... clearly reverse ajax is not what you think it is if you have doubts about this

Comment: I read about reverse from here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-reverseajax1/

Comment: sorry reverse ajax in above comment.
what I want is to hit a URL once and read the responses from it continuously without requesting again and again.
And I can't change anything on server side.

Comment: @SandeepJaluthairya - if you have a back-end that serves a (one) response when it receives a request, you _need_ to change the back-end if you want it to continue to provide continuous output after receiving an(one) initial request. I mean, you are expecting a different behaviour from the server-side code after all - this obviously, requires different code to perform it.